# Executar um comando do Postgres via ssh e trazer o resultado para váriavél ou txt

Tags: postgresql, ssh

Amigos, estou com a dificuldade de criar script para efetuar um UPDATE em um banco de dados conectando via ssh estando fora do servidor segue abaixo meu código.

**Comando:**

```
ssh hostname 'psql -d database -U usuario --command="select host,name,phone_number,active from trunks where id = '22'"'
```

**Resultado**:

```
    host     |        name         | phone_number | active 
--------------+---------------------+--------------+--------
 100.200.1.5| teste | 0000222      | t
(1 registro)*
```

Ok, para o select fuciona porem estou com dificuldades em tratar as Aspas '' para efetuar um `UPDATE` ou `ALTERTABLE` poderiam me ajudar como tratar aspas no comando segue o retorno que tenho.

**Comando:**

```
ssh hostname 'psql -d database -U usuario --command="update trunks set active = 't'  where id = '22'"'
```

**Erro**

```
ERROR:  column "t" does not exist
LINHA 1: update trunks set active **= t**  where id = 22
```

Diz que a coluna T não existe mas T é o parametro `FALSE / TRUE` mesmo se eu coloco aspas ' ' não reconhece poderiam me ajudar.

Comment: pretendo executar este comando de dentro de uma variavél hoje consigo executar pro select, porem para update tenho esse problema que citei. result=$(ssh hostname '"(`psql -d database -U usuario -A -t --command="select host,name,phone_number,active from trunks where id = '$LINHA';"`"');

Comment: Como você utiliza ' para delimitar seu comando psql então duplique as ' internas: ssh hostname 'psql -d database -U usuario --command="update trunks set active = ''t''  where id = ''22''"', duas ' e não uma ".

Comment: coloquei duplicado mas agora retorna erro de sitaxe ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINHA 1: update trunks set active = t where id = ;